# Python pip module issues on Kali Linux

Tags: python, kali-linux

I am on my Kali Linux. When I run `sudo python3 Storm-Breaker.py`, I get an error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyngrok'

But when I import pyngrok in an ordinary python file and then run it, it works out fine.
Please please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall install the package before using it.

Run the following command to install the package and its dependencies.

```
pip install pyngrok
```

Comment: Yes, I did that but it showed 'requirement already satisfied'.

Comment: @Jason [This issue](https://github.com/DarkSecDevelopers/HiddenEye-Legacy/issues/668) might help you

Comment: Thanks, @MJK618, when I did 'sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt', it worked!

Comment: How should I close this question?

Comment: you can mark this answer as correct answer for your question, it will help others who might face similar error in future

Answer (score -1):

**You can try using the following command**

```
sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```